# IndexErrors in python

Tags: python

```
#To Find the first occurance of a substring
def getIndex(string, sequence):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == sequence[0]:
            try:
                if string[i+1:(i+1+len(sequence)-1)] == sequence[1:]:
                    return i
                else:
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                print('Array out of bounds substring doesnt exist')
    else:
        return 'not found'

print(getIndex('skyscrapper', 'erss'))
```

In the above code the letter **e** is present at index 9 so when I do **string[i+1:(i+1+len(sequence)-1)]** equivalent to **string[10:13]** shouldn't it be throwing an **IndexError** since the index 12 doesnt exist in the string?

Comment: Obviously it should, will throw index error

Comment: I have tried the code it doesn't throw an error

Comment: "The slice of s from i to j is defined as the sequence of items with index k such that i <= k < j. If i or j is greater than len(s), use len(s)" https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List slicing works differently than accessing value of the list in given index.

List slicing actually won't never return IndexError - in worst case it would return []

```
foo = []
print(foo[5:12])
# Above prints []
```

Comment: So, basically in foo[i:j] if i is an index in the list and j isn't, it would print all the elements from i to the end of the list something like foo[i:] ?

Comment: Yes, [start:end:step]

Answer (score 1):

**Python** doesn't throw error when ranging in **string**. One way you can achieve your goal by adding `ck = string[i+len(sequence)]` inside the `try` block.

Try this one...

```py
def getIndex(string, sequence):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == sequence[0]:
            try:
                # this will result IndexError if index out of range
                ck = string[i+len(sequence)]
                if string[i+1:(i+1+len(sequence)-1)] == sequence[1:]:
                    return i
                else:
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                print('Array out of bounds substring doesnt exist')
    else:
        return 'not found'

print(getIndex('skyscrapper', 'erss'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have to write a custom function for finding the index of substring. python's string has the method index that does that.

e.g.

```
s="telephone"
print(s.index("phone"))
```

gives you 4

by the way I run your code and it is returning not found

Comment: Yes I know there's a built in method I just started learning so I was just experimenting with a lot of stuff.